# Save filesystem from list of paths into sql database

Tags: java, sql-server, data-structures, filesystems

I've a list of file paths in `ArrayList<String>` like this:

```
/a/b/file1
/a/b/file2
/a/b/file3
/a/b/file4
/b/d/file5
/e/c/file6
```

Then I map them into pojo like this:

```
  public class FileData {
     public String id;
     public String name;
     public String path;

     // store parent of this file or folder. If value is null, mean file/folder in root
     public String parentId; 

     public boolean isFolder;
  }
```

And here is database schema for it:

```
 FileData

 id | name | path | parent_id | is_folder
 1  | file1|  /b  |    2      |  false
 2  |  b   |  /a  |    3      |  true
 3  |  a   |  /   |    null   |  true
```

I wonder is there any fast way to **parse `ArrayList<String>` above into `ArrayList<FileData>` which has child - parent relationship**, then I can save into database?

Comment: Have you heard of using an ORM tool such as Hibernate?  By the way, I don't follow your output table.

Comment: It can be done in database side as well. Which DBMS you are using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just update my question to make it clear. The problem is that I need the way to parse list file path into list `FileData` object, which has child - parent relationship. I can save this list into database by myself

Comment: @Prdp well, my problem is that I need the way to parse list file path into list FileData object, which has child - parent relationship, I can handle database saving by myself

Comment: Can't you split the string by '/' operator and then the last element will always be a file value, so it will have is_folder = false and any elements before it will be it's parent. Let me try this question in a bit.... give me like one hour of time, not near my laptop right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the implementation of the program that creates an ArrayList() for you to be able to store in a database.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

  public static class FileData {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String path;

    // store parent of this file or folder. If value is null, mean file/folder in root
    public String parentId; 

    public boolean isFolder;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    // inserting some dummy values
    filePaths.add("/a/b/file1");
    filePaths.add("/a/b/file2");
    filePaths.add("/a/b/file3");
    filePaths.add("/a/b/file3");
    filePaths.add("/a/b/file4");
    filePaths.add("/b/d/file5");
    filePaths.add("/e/c/file6");

    HashMap<String, Integer> pathId = new HashMap<>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> mCheck = new HashMap<>();

    ArrayList<FileData> fileDataSql = new ArrayList<>();

    int cntId = 1;

    for(String s:filePaths) {
      String[] sSplit = s.split("/");
      for(int i=1; i<sSplit.length; i++) {
        if(!pathId.containsKey(sSplit[i])) {
          pathId.put(sSplit[i], cntId);
          cntId++;
        }
        FileData fileDataObj = new FileData();
        fileDataObj.id = Integer.toString(pathId.get(sSplit[i]));
        fileDataObj.name = sSplit[i];

        // Here I am checking if this is the first element or not, if yes then it has null parentId and / as path
        if(i == 1) {
          fileDataObj.parentId = "null";
          fileDataObj.path = "/";
        } else {
          fileDataObj.parentId = Integer.toString(pathId.get(sSplit[i-1]));
          fileDataObj.path = "/" + sSplit[i-1];
        }

        if(i == sSplit.length-1) {
          fileDataObj.isFolder = false;
        } else {
          fileDataObj.isFolder = true;
        }
        if(!mCheck.containsKey(sSplit[i])) {
          mCheck.put(sSplit[i], 1);
          fileDataSql.add(fileDataObj);
        }
      }
    }

    for(FileData obj : fileDataSql) {
      System.out.println(obj.id + " " + obj.name + " " + obj.path + " " + obj.parentId + " " + obj.isFolder);
    }
  }
}
```

I might have used a lot of space but it does what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I updated your code a little bit and it works. I just think about recursive to resolve this problem as well